# prevent users to post multiple submission by clicking submit button multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-templates

Here's the problem I'm having, when user submits a post and click submit button twice before new page gets loaded then two same posts are made. I thought I could fix this with python code since I'm using django(restricting user to post only one in one min;what I did http://dpaste.com/313A0A4)but even after that the issue exists. Here's my html code (with my try that doesn't work)

```
{% block content %}
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="/add_post/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
<!--{% for tag in person.tags.all %}{{ tag.word }} {% endfor %}-->

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Post">
    </form>
    {% endblock %}

        {% include 'footer.html' %}
<script>


jQuery('form').on('submit', function(){ 
    if(jQuery("input[name=submit]").hasClass('active'))
        { return false; }
         else{ 
            jQuery("input[name=submit]").addClass('active'); } });

</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add e.preventDefault(). In form.submit, after clicking the button for the fiirst time, can you disable the button

Comment: I don't know Django but this is typically solved by disabling the submit button using JavaScript and sending an AJAX request to the server. Once that's done you can use JavaScript to show the new post and enable the button or simply use `window.location = url` to redirect them to the page with the new post

Comment: @AviahLaor ah, hello...your approach doesn't work. I fixed the error but this doesn't work like I mentioned up

Comment: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/doublesubmit/ is this the right approach?

Comment: @Robert what do you mean by disabling the submit button?how to submit without the button?..hmmm

Comment: @winixxee I meant prevent the user from clicking the submit button, the button would remain visible but would change color or say "Please wait..." to indicate to the user something is happening in the background. The example you linked in the answer is the right approach.

Comment: oh yeah that's really good idea thank you...hmmm can you give me some help with this...I'm very bad in js

Comment: @winixxee added my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would solve your problem with JavaScript. I am assuming the form is on it's own page and you have to redirect to `/posts` after the post is created.

HTML:

```
<form id="post-form" method="post">
  <p class="bg-danger" id="error-message"></p>
  <input id="submit-post-form" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#post-form').submit(handleSubmit);
});

function handleSubmit(e) {
    var $submit = $('#submit-post-form');
    $submit.prop('disabled', true)
        .addClass('disabled')
        .attr('value', 'Please Wait...');

    // Let Python do it's thing
    var request = $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "add_post",
        data: $('#post-form').serialize()
    });

    // Once Python has inserted record in database
    request.done(function(response) {
        // Display error, if any occured
        if (response.error) {
           $('#error-message').html(response.error);
           $submit.prop('disabled', false)
                  .removeClass('disabled');
           return;
        }

        // Assuming posts are found at /posts
        window.location = 'posts';

        // If you want to get fancy with the redirect you can return it from python
        // window.location = response.url;
    });

    // Prevent regular submit functionality
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it says Uncaught The editor instance "id_content" is already attached to the provided element.a

Answer (score 0):

Hi kindly check the following fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/b5c75zjr/1/

**HTML**

```
<input class="txt" type="text">
<input class="btn active" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Post">
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.btn').on('click', function(e){
 if($('.btn').hasClass('active'))
 {
 e.preventDefault();
 }
 else{
 $(this).addClass('active');
 alert('hi');
 }
 });

 $('.txt').on('change', function(){
 $('.btn').removeClass('active');
 });
});
```

maybe something similar?

Comment: wait I don't understand this, I tried fiddle but it only alerts me "hi" when I click the button...

Comment: i just created the logic... replace form submission code in place of alert.. form will be submitted only once i.e first time and hence preventing multiple submissions...

Comment: so this is the right approach, http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/doublesubmit/?

Comment: yea but you should enable 'submit' once the form is submitted else users cant post new posts after posting 1st post